# How to group by 2 array elements in linq

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, group-by

Out of the database I'm trying to create a list of objects which contains only distinct values.

For grouping by only 1 column this works NICE

```
List<object[]> myList =
    myDataTable.AddRange(entity.MyTable.AsEnumerable().Select(e => new object[]{ e.id, e.foreignKey, e.id, e.name }).GroupBy(x => x[0]).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

But for 2 columns I get errors:

```
List<object[]> myList =
    myDataTable.AddRange(entity.MyTable.AsEnumerable().Select(e => new object[]{ e.id, e.foreignKey, e.id, e.name }).GroupBy(x => new {x[0], x[1]}).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

The error message is:

> *Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.*

Now my question is: How can I group by 2 array elements?

Answer (score 1):

As the exception message states, you need to declare the member in anonymous type declaration of `GroupBy`, do it like this:-

```
List<object[]> myList =
    myDataTable.AddRange(entity.MyTable.AsEnumerable()
              .Select(e => new object[]{ e.id, e.foreignKey, e.id, e.name })
              .GroupBy(x => new { a = x[0], b = x[1] }).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

What's you don't understand in error? You just should give property names for your anonymous object. You can do it like this:

```
List<object[]> myList =
myDataTable
.AddRange(entity.MyTable.AsEnumerable()
.Select(e => new object[]{ e.id, e.foreignKey, e.id, e.name })
.GroupBy(x => new 
{ 
    propertyName1 = x[0], 
    propertyName2 = x[1]
})
.Select(x => x.First())
.ToList();
```

Comment: The problem was mostly that I thought too much complexity into the error message (thus I thought the problem was more complex than it really was)

Comment: Sometimes we need just to stop for a minute and don't think about anything to solve a problem. When i face a problem like that my teamlead loves to say - "go to sleep and everything will be fine"